# "NullReferenceException" when trying to set DataGridView column width, brings through data fine otherwise

Tags: c#, datagridview

I bring through data from a Stored Procedure, this can be displayed in the datagrid fine, however setting column width keeps throwing a null exception:

```
dataGridView2.Columns[x].Width = 60;
```

Full Code:

```
public void Populate_Data_Grid2_All()
    {
        string sqlQuery = "EXEC sp_CG_GMR_Select_Specific_Data";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var myTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(myTable);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = myTable;
        }

        dataGridView2.Columns[0].Width = 60;
        dataGridView2.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = 40;
        dataGridView2.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.Columns[2].Width = 50;
        dataGridView2.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.Columns[3].Width = 250;
        dataGridView2.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.Columns[4].Width = 100;
        dataGridView2.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView2.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
    }
```

Setting ReadOnly and the cell styles don't throw errors, but setting the width does. This code is exactly the same as what I do for another data grid in the program, which brings through more columns from a different procedure. The procedure I'm trying to format now doesn't have any blank values brought through or anything.

**Edit:**
For clarity, here is the code for the other data grid doing the same thing which works perfectly fine. The second datagrid is also a copy of the first, so all setting of it are the same (I've also checked to make sure)

Code:

```
public void Populate_Data_Grid1(string DataExists, string Scheme)
        {
            string NoCurrentPeriodData = "EXEC sp_CG_GMR_Scheme_Manual_Entry_Template @Scheme = '"+Scheme+"'";

            string YesCurrentPeriodData = "EXEC sp_CG_GMR_Current_Period_Data @Scheme = '"+Scheme+"'";

            string sqlQuery;

            if(DataExists())
            {
                sqlQuery = YesCurrentPeriodData;
            }
            else
            {
                sqlQuery = NoCurrentPeriodData;
            }

            using (var connection   = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (var command      = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
            using (var adapter      = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var myTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(myTable);
                dg_Data1.DataSource = myTable;
            }

            //--Data Grid Column Properties--\\
            dg_Data1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            dg_Data1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
            dg_Data1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
            dg_Data1.Columns[6].Visible = false;

            dg_Data1.Columns[1].Width = 60;
            dg_Data1.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
            dg_Data1.Columns[3].Width = 40;
            dg_Data1.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
            dg_Data1.Columns[5].Width = 50;
            dg_Data1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
            dg_Data1.Columns[7].Width = 250;
            dg_Data1.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;
            dg_Data1.Columns[8].Width = 100;
            dg_Data1.Columns[8].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
            //dg_Data1.Columns[8].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D";

            btn_SaveValues.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Comment: You probably do not have 5 columns in the datatable. Or not set the DGV to autocreatecolumns..which line is it that throws?

Comment: @TaW Theres certainly 5 columns, plus its erroring on "Columns[0]" which it wouldn't do if there were more/less than 5 columns. Also it is set to autocreatecolumns as its displays all the data fine as long as I don't try and set a column width.

Comment: Hm. Set a breakpoint on that line then and drill into the columns to see if you can find anything funny there..

Comment: If the `Width` fails due to `NullException`, the `ReadOnly` will almost certainly be also failed due to `NullException`... The reason why only `Width` fails but not `ReadOnly` is simply because the `Width` comes first in your code... please check the columns, whether they are really exist before you set the `Width` and `ReadOnly` properties. Use debugger to do that..

Comment: @Ian Readonly does fail, I comment out the set width and it runs the readonly fine but fails at the next set width.

Comment: @Vereonix ah yes, use your debugger to find the number of columns your data grid actually have... that will be the most helpful step

Comment: @TaW I'm able to manually enter a width value at the width line when it stops at the debug, it then runs fine when I click continue, and all widths are applied correctly. This is strange.

Comment: Yes this is strange. Are there any other settings you may have done like AutoSizeMode or hidden columns?

Comment: You're passing a string "true"?  Use a boolean.  You don't have to open the connection when using an adapter.  It will open and close it for you.  Put `Debug.WriteLine(dg_Data1.Columns.Count.ToString());` a line before the error occurs.  When do you call this procedure in your code?

Comment: @LarsTech The first function I'm running on Load, the second one which works I run when the user selects an option from a dropdown.

Comment: Try running it in the OnShown override instead.

Comment: @LarsTech Running it on an event other than on load it works fine, I've altered my program to accommodate this. Still not sure why it doesn't like setting width when data is retried on Load.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was having this exact problem and stumbled upon the inconspicuous solution of
setting the column's **AutoSizeMode** before setting **Width**. Example:

```
dataGridView2.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
dataGridView2.Columns[0].Width = 60;
dataGridView2.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
```